# Add Searchable dropdown in jqgrid for inline edit and add features?

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to JQgrid and want to implement a searchable dropdown in jqgrid column. I have used simple dropdown but cannot find any help for searchable dropdown.

Comment: Look at [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) method and define `stype: "select", searchoptions: { value: "..."}` The `value` describes the options in the dropdown. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm) and [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#filtering)

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this Example...
Here is an Auto Populated List with Grid...

```
http://germanrumm.eu/examples/jqgrid-autocomplete/
```

get your code from Here...

```
http://germanrumm.eu/adding-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-jqgrid-edit-form/
```

Comment: That appears to be the thing i was searching for. I will try it out and will let you know if it works for me or not. :)